# What do the dashed lines in the outliner mean?

Tags: parent, outliner

Two of my objects are somehow linked to each other in that one of the items are copying itself on the other but I can't figure out how. I don't think its instancing because when I unparent the object and reparent it with another one it doesn't work, and its not using a hair modifier to do it either.

**Main question:** What relationship are the dashed lines in the outliner indicative of?

I know the green triangle with three dots is a mesh and the solid orange triangle is an object. I pointed an arrow to it in case its hard to see.

[image]

Comment: Just to add to the answer - the green triangle has nothing to do with this. It's just mesh data for the *leaves.002* object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dashed line means the *child object* isn't present in the same collection.
It probably got left in a different one.

The *parent-child* relationship still exists, but the *'misplaced child'* :( won't be treated as a part of the collection (for instancing, particles or simulations)

[image]